# How to create a quiz app Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Hello i east create an app similar to the image (Duolingo).
I do know how to create that type of question. I need on press an option it locate in the top to generate a phrase.

Any idea
What widgets I can use?
[image]

Comment: It is better that you report here: http://www.flutter.io/widgets/layout

Answer (score 1):

Your question is hard to understand and too broad.

To make draggable words that can be placed on the line above, you have to use `Draggable` and `DraggableTarget`.

Of course you will also need other layout widgets like a `Row`, you will need a `StatefulWidget` to store and display the words which were already inserted.